# Why Hibernate updates database when concat string?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

In the db i have one single table which contains Services and SubServices.

I need to create a function which creates a list to be used in a  formatted like this:

> - Service 1
>
>   - service 1.a
>   - service 1.b
> - Service 2
> - Service 3
>
>   - service 3.a

I did the function below, but I don't understand why, this updates the db
adding *& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;* !

I never call session.update.

Thanks

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Service> getFormattedServices() 
    {


        //lista main_services
        List<Service> main_services = getMainServices();

        List<Service> result = new ArrayList();

        Iterator<Service> iterator = main_services.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Service tmp = iterator.next();

            //add the main service
            result.add(tmp);

            //scan of subservices
            Iterator<Service>iterator_s = tmp.getChildren().iterator();
            while (iterator_s.hasNext())
            {
                Service tmp2 = iterator_s.next();

                /*
                **********
                * why this line updates the row in DB ???
                *
                */
                tmp2.setTitolo("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".concat(tmp2.getTitolo()));

                //add the subservice
                result.add(tmp2);

                tmp2 = null;
            }
            iterator_s = null;

            tmp = null;
        }
        iterator = null;

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have your object state is [`persistent`](http://achuthan.blogspot.com/2011/02/hibernate-object-states_01.html). So any changes will be detected and synced with db. If you do this in transaction, Hibernate will sync before closing transaction(not for any single change it hits), otherwise it hits for every single objects attribute change.

```
Persistance:
* A persistance instance has a representation in database and an identifier value. 
It might have been just saved or loaded. It will be associated with a hibernate 
session.
* Hibernate will detect any changes made to an object in persistent state and 
synchronize the state 
with the database when the unit of work completes.
```

Answer (score 1):

What you get from the Hibernate queries and session methods are attached entities. Any modification you make to such attached entities is transparently saved to the database, without any need to call any method. That's an essential feature of Hibernate, that you must be aware of. It tremendously helps.

Since your method modifies the entities while they're still attached (i.e. while the session used to get them is still opened), obviously, the database is modified.

You shouldn't modify an entity simply to display it with some spaces before it. The code used to display the entities shouldn't modify entities. If you persist in this wrong direction, then at least detach the entities from the session before modifying them, by using `session.evict()`.

EDIT: to display your list of services, you simply need two loops:

```
for (Service mainService : mainServices) {
    out.println(mainService.getTitle();
    for (Service subService: mainService.getChildren()) {
        out.println("&nbsp;&npsb;" + subService.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Of course, this should probably be part of your view. Assuming you're using JSPs, it would be as simple as

```
<ul>
<c:forEach var="mainService" items="${mainServices}">
    <li>
        <c:out value="${mainService.title}"/>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="subService" items="${mainService.children}">
            <li><c:out value="${subService.title}"/></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: very clear. In your last sentence, you suggest me that it's not good do this only for display, but so, how can i have a custom list of <Service> only for display?  Thanks

Comment: See my edited answer. Entities are your model. Presentation logic doesn't go in the model. It goes in the view. And prepending HTML non-breaking spaces to a title is purely presentation logic.

Comment: thank you very much, but i'm using Thymeleaf and I need this function for a <select>... As I couldn't find how to do that in template page, I decided to do this in controller (calling the function object of this answer)